# Create and manipulate the buttons array in java and android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I am designing the simple addition quiz App where 2 numbers are generated randomly and then they are added.

One correct answer and 3 wrong answers are then setText() to respective buttons.

I want to use Array of buttons to do the same instead of allotting answers to the buttons individually as there might be large number of buttons in the future that need to be allotted Text.

Currently I am using ArrayList to allot its elements to buttons one by one.
I am not facing any problem, but this is okay as far as there are only 4 buttons.For larger number of buttons I would prefer array to allot text.

```
//Part 1: Declaration
Button optionA,optionB,optionC,optionD;
ArrayList<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Part 2: Allot address
optionA = (Button) findViewbyid(R.id.optionA); // button variable name and address are same
optionB = (Button) findViewbyid(R.id.optionB);
optionC = (Button) findViewbyid(R.id.optionC);
optionD = (Button) findViewbyid(R.id.optionD);

//Part 3: Send Arraylist values to button:

        optionA.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(0)));
        optionB.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(1)));
        optionC.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(2)));
        optionD.setText(Integer.toString(answers.get(3)));

//Please note that entire code is not given here. Value is assigned to ArrayList elements using answers.add(i,value) in for loop
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? And please don't use the android-studio tag unless your problem refers to the IDE Android-Studio.

Comment: Hello sir, I am using it for IDE android studio. That's why I used android studio tag

Comment: Yeah but your problem refers not to the IDE itself, but to Android

Comment: Oh ok. Got the point, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Just as you have used `new ArrayList<Integer>()` to create a dynamic list of answers, you can use `new ArrayList<Button>()` to create a dynamic list of buttons.